# jQuery .toggle() breaking a line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on http://beta.mobilityhosting.com/services/ and wanting to use jQuery's .toggle() function on the "Learn More..." links. I have it implemented on the first link but when the hidden content is revealed, a line is breaking.

I cannot figure out how to prevent this. I just want all of the content below the link to descend. Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<p>` element takes up the whole line, so all you need to do is change

```
display: inline-block
```

I already dynamically edited with Chrome on your site and it brings up the Hide.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have thememodinfo as a paragraph. Can't you make that an span instead?

Also thememodinfo get's style 'display: block' which will cause the next element to got o next line.

Can you make it 'display: inline-block'?

Comment: I am already using 'display:none' on the thememodinfo class to hide it. Just to clarify, I want all the content below the link to descend as opposed to the current behavior of the "Anything to WordPress..." <h2> breaking.